# Add user credentials to access server drive path from winforms in app.config vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to create upload file to the server drive c. 
But there is user credentials require to access the server file path.
So i use this code in app.config

```
<configuration>
       ....
     <appSettings>
       <add key="DocumentVault" value="\\10.100.100.10\C$\SomePath\SomeWhere\Else\"/> 
     </appSettings>
    ....
</configuration>
```

How to add the user credentials inside?

Comment: I'd suggest not putting user credentials (if you mean username and password) in the app.config.

Comment: then how to put it in winforms?

Comment: I think this problem would be better solved by creating a network share mapped to the server path of interest. Then, assuming you're in an AD environment, grant access to the users (or maybe `Everyone`) that you want to be able to access this share.